# How to install and run Mercurial server on a remote Linux host with limited user rights?

Tags: mercurial, remote-server

I have a remote managed hosting Linux server and I would like to install and run a Mercurial server on it to communicate with from local repositories (clone, pull, push).

The server has Apache, PHP, MySql, Python and RubyOnRails. 
I can also access the remote system over SSH, but the command repertoire is limited: e.g. there is no such thing as apt-get, so I cannot download and deploy the server directly.

Is there any possibility to bypass these limitations and have a Mercurial server operating on such a server? Or does any other Version Control system exist that would allow this kind of usage? Is there probably a PHP- or Python-driven Version Control Server around (which I failed to find)?

Answer (score 3):

This depends on the restrictions set in place. Mercurial is a normal Python program and the Mercurial server is part of the normal distribution. If you are using SSH as a transport protocol, nothing but a Mercurial installation in your $PATH is required. For HTTP access you will need to either run the Mercurial `hg serve` command or install the necessary wsgicgi module.

Now let's assume you want to access the repositories via SSH, and only need a Mercurial installation, but cannot run apt-get, consider the following:

1. You must have Python installed
2. You can try installing Mercurial from sources by downloading the tarball from https://www.mercurial-scm.org/downloads.

   1. Run `make install PREFIX=~/mercurial` to install the Mercurial distribution to `~/mercurial`.
   2. Ensure `~/mercurial` is in your $PATH during your SSH session by adding `export PATH=$PATH:~/mercurial` to your `~/.profile`.
3. If you cannot install Mercurial from sources, you can consider building Mercurial on a compatible Linux systems. E.g. your servers runs Ubuntu 19.04, and you run locally Ubuntu 19.04. Install the distribution as described to your local directory and rsync the distribution to your server.

   1. On your local linux machine: `make install PREFIX=~/mercurial` to install the Mercurial distribution to `~/mercurial`.
   2. `rsync -avzP ~/mercurial server:~/mercurial`
   3. Set path variable to `~/mercurial` as described above.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try to do as you describe. (though I am not sure I will be able to run make install...) Next time I have access to that server.

Comment: I have downloaded the source files of 'mercurial-5.1', unzipped and copied it to a folder on the server. Then I tried to run make install from within this folder. First, I got an error "Python 3.4 detected. ... this error can be suppressed by defining the HGPYTHON3 environment variable..." I failed to switch to Python 2.7 on server and added the environment variable. After that, I am getting "File "setup.py", line 408, in <module> .. etc from mercurial import version ... AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'LazyLoader'

Comment: I have had another attempt: changed 

PYTHON?=python

to

PYTHON?=/usr/bin/python2.7

in setup.py. It has almost functioned, but in the end I got 

"creating /usr/local/lib/python2.7
error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7': Permission denied
make: *** [Makefile:85: install-bin] Error 1"

Any ideas how to deal with this? TIA.